# **Capybara Bcrypt Rspec** User SIgn Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, bcrypt

Ok, so I would like to test a User Sign up for a rails application with Rspec

```
    require 'rails_helper.rb'

    feature 'Creating User' do
      scenario 'User signs up' do
        # visit the User sign up
        visit '/'
        click_link 'New User'
        # expect the page to have a specific text
        expect(page).to have_content('New User')
        # fill out the bits of the form that we need.
        fill_in 'Email', with: 'sean@cookio.com'
        fill_in 'First name', with: 'sean'
        fill_in 'Last name', with: 'sean'
        fill_in 'City', with: 'blah'
        fill_in 'State', with: 'blah'
        fill_in 'Zip', with: '33333'
        fill_in 'Phone', with: '555-555-5555'
        fill_in 'Password', with: 'secret1'
        fill_in 'Password confirmation', with: 'secret1'
        # click the submit button
        click_button 'Create User'
        # expect the page that we're sent to have a specific text
        expect(page).to have_content('created user and logged in')
      end
    end
```

I am presented with this error

```
    Failures:

      1) Creating User User signs up
        Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_content('created user and
        logged in')
        SystemExit:
          exit
```

All my content seems to be correct. However, it is staying on the current page. If I run the information in the application itself, it works as intended. But, it is not working with Rspec. Any ideas?

Comment: What webdriver are you using? Which page has the text "CookioHomeNew"? What does `bcrypt` have to do with this? As a general rule, if you are not on the page you expected to be it might be a waiting issue. You can check it with [saving/screenshoting](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#debugging) the page and some `sleep`s.

Comment: The CookioHomeNew is just the navigation menu; I cut some of the text off so the post wasnt to long.But, it is the same user sign up page. I just added screenshots if the `Rspec` fails. All my text fields are blank, I dont know if that is normal. I will try to make it `sleep` now.